# Pandas index behavior when concatenating 1 row data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am relatively new to python/pandas and having trouble understanding how pandas indexes work. When I iterate over the rows of a data frame and create a new data frame with the same number of rows and then try to add a series that existed in the original data frame, the added series only repeats its first element.

Here is a simple example with inline prints of the data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(1,6), 'col2': range(6,11), 'col3': range(11, 16)})

print(df)

       col1  col2  col3
    0     1     6    11
    1     2     7    12
    2     3     8    13 
    3     4     9    14
    4     5    10    15

col3 = df.col3

iters = df.shape[0]
pred_list = []

for i in range(iters):
    pred1 = df.loc[i,"col1"] + df.loc[i,"col2"]
    pred2 = df.loc[i,"col1"] * df.loc[i,"col2"]
    pred_row = pd.DataFrame([[pred1, pred2]], columns = ["p1", "p2"])
    pred_list.append(pred_row)

pred_df = pd.concat(pred_list, axis = 0)

pred_df["col3"] = col3

print(pred_df)

       p1  p2  col3
    0   7   6    11
    0   9  14    11
    0  11  24    11
    0  13  36    11
    0  15  50    11

pred_df_reset = pred_df.reset_index()

pred_df_reset["col3"] = col3

print(pred_df_reset)

       index  p1  p2  col3
    0      0   7   6    11
    1      0   9  14    12
    2      0  11  24    13
    3      0  13  36    14
    4      0  15  50    15
```

I can see that the index is 0 for all rows in the first `pred_df`. But how can I avoid this happening? I'm guessing using `.reset_index()` for everything is not a good habit to get into.

Comment: `pred_df = pd.concat(pred_list, axis = 0, ignore_index=True)` will concatenate `pred_list` and generate a new index at the same time. But [jpp's vectorized approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51271201/190597) shows a faster, better way to handle the calculation which avoids the need for `ignore_index=True`.

Comment: I should add the vectorized approach does not work in my real-life example because I am doing recursive time series predictions that must be done row-by-row on the prediction data.

Answer (score 2):

As per @unutbu's comment, you can tell Pandas to ignore index when concatenating: `pd.concat(pred_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)`. Below are more efficient methods to handle your problem.

#### List of lists to pd.DataFrame

You can construct a list of lists, then feed this to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor directly. This will also be more efficient: `list.append` is cheaper than `pd.DataFrame.append`.

```
col3 = df.col3
iters = df.shape[0]
pred_list = []

for i in range(iters):
    pred1 = df.loc[i,"col1"] + df.loc[i,"col2"]
    pred2 = df.loc[i,"col1"] * df.loc[i,"col2"]
    pred_list.append([pred1, pred2])

pred_df = pd.DataFrame(pred_list, columns=["p1", "p2"])
pred_df["col3"] = col3

print(pred_df)

   p1  p2  col3
0   7   6    11
1   9  14    12
2  11  24    13
3  13  36    14
4  15  50    15
```

#### Vectorised approach

The more important point is your operations can be vectorised to avoid expensive manual loops:

```
s1 = df.col1 + df.col2
s2 = df.col1 * df.col2
s3 = df.col3

res = pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], axis=1)
res.columns = ['p1', 'p2', 'col3']

print(res)

   p1  p2  col3
0   7   6    11
1   9  14    12
2  11  24    13
3  13  36    14
4  15  50    15
```